# JSHint error: "E001 - Bad option"

Tags: javascript, jshint, atom-editor

I'm working on some ES6 javascript code, and `linter-jshint` keeps throwing this error.

[image: Error E001 Bad Option]

I tried looking up all [JSHint options](http://jshint.com/docs/options/). At first I added `{"esversion": 6}` to a .jshintrc file on my user directory. This was when the error started to appear. Then I tried going for the deprecated `{"esnext": true}`. The error just changed to another one, so I went back.

This option should work, I don't get why it's showing this error. It's a valid option, isn't it?

By the way, I'm using Atom.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of JSHint?...

Comment: If you're referring to JSHint as an Atom package, yes. It's up to date.

Comment: I had almost the same E0001 error but with 'extract' instead of 'esversion' with a fresh installed atom, jshint, linter. And the error was coming from errors in my .jshintrc file

Comment: @Mic How did you resolved the error? Could you post a snippet of your .jshintrc? Maybe I'm just formatting it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working .jshintrc file, I had a wrong property error in it, giving the same kind of message:

```
{
  "predef": [ "$", "jQuery", "text", "$p", "window", "document", "console", "parent" ],
  "curly":                true,
  "eqeqeq":               true,
  "funcscope":            true,
  "futurehostile":        true,
  "latedef":              true,
  "nonbsp":               true,
  "notypeof":             true,
  "shadow":               "outer",
  "singleGroups":         true,
  "undef":                true,
  "unused":               true,

  "debug":                true,
  "scripturl":            true,

  "-W079":                true
}
```

Something useful.
If you `Ctrl + Alt + Cmd + L` (on a Mac) 
Atom is reloaded, and take the last changes into account.

Comment: Seems you got rid of the error but haven't specified the javascript version in use. Is that correct?

Comment: I need to stay compatible with older browsers, and do not work with newer version for now

Answer (score 1):

I had one line with

```
// jshint ignore:line //and wanted to add some more information in the comment
```

removing the additional comment fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check `package.json`.

Stumbled across this error because `package.json` had:

```
{ 
  jshintConfig": {
    "extends": "./node_modules/jsgreat/es6/.jshintrc"
  }
}
```

Which is invalid, `extends` can only be used in a `.jshintrc` file.